# Android decode json data

Tags: android, android-layout

How to decode this Json data in android i reied the following code

```
 [
   {"data": 
      {"url": 
       {
         "url": "http://www.xxxxxx.com/story.html", "title":"some data","source_url": "www.somesite.com", "summary": "\n \n \n \n \n somedata again"
       }
      }
   }
 ]
```

Java code

`EDIT:`

```
   HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);
    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();

   HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);  
  HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();




    String r1 = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
    System.out.println("printing response now "+r1);


    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "data received"+r1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(r1);
    JSONArray venues = json.getJSONObject("data")
              .getJSONArray("url")
              .getJSONObject(0)
              .getJSONArray("url");

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "data received"+venues, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

If venus should be the url itself, the code should be:

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(r1);
String venues = json.getJSONObject(0)
                .getJSONObject("data")
                .getJSONObject("url")
                .getString("url");
```

Comment: No this doesnt work getJSONObject gives an error in this case

Comment: I get an exception as 08-18 14:35:51.806: INFO/System.out(935): Exceptionorg.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: So you have some data before what you showed. first separate the json, so r1 will only contain the json string, not the whole html.

Comment: No r1 is just the json response derived from a request from as showed..Please see the edit..